# cant connect user to google cloud sql database

Tags: php, sql, google-app-engine

I am attempting to connect to a database in an instance on Google cloud sql but it is telling me access is denied.

Im just wondering am I missing something here...

1. I have requested an IP and inserted that into the authorized networks
2. I have created a database and set a user using SQL prompt (found in original view of Google APIs Console) and granted all privileges to that user for that database.
3. I have listed the users in that database to make sure "adrian" exists and that I have done that correctly.
4. I have insured the app being used to connect is authorized in the access control
5. I have set a root password in the access control section.

Here is my app.yaml file...

```
application: guestbookadrian12
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: .*
script: main.php

env_variables:
DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST: ''
DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME: 'root'
DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME: 'guestbookadrian12'
PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE: '/cloudsql/guestbookadrian12:my-cloudsql-instance'
PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME: 'adrian'
PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
PRODUCTION_DB_NAME: 'guestbookadrian12'
```

Here is some php code where it creates the connection...

```
 if (strpos(getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE'), 'Development') === false) {
$conn = mysqli_connect(null,
                       getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME'),
                       getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD'),
                       null,
                       null,
                       getenv('PRODUCTION_CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE'));
$db = getenv('PRODUCTION_DB_NAME');
//echo 'Database = : '.$db;
 } else {
$conn = mysqli_connect(getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_HOST'), 
                       getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_USERNAME'),
                       getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_PASSWORD'));
$db = getenv('DEVELOPMENT_DB_NAME');
}

if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Could not connect to database: $conn->connect_error " .
    "[$conn->connect_errno]");
 }

 if ($conn->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $db") === FALSE) {
die("Could not create database: $conn->error [$conn->errno]");
 }
```

The error Im getting is

```
Could not create database: Access denied for user 'adrian'@'localhost' to database 'guestbookadrian12' [1044]
```

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a user 'adrian'@'localhost' or just 'adrian'? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Thank you, thats exactly what was wrong, I was only granting privileges to adrian, its working now :) , feel free to use that as an answer